# Exception in JBoss Forge 2.13.2

Tags: jboss, jboss-forge

I'm trying to run JBoss Forge in an Ubuntu 14.04. Forge runs but when i issue any commands (cd, scaffold-setup, command-list, etc) it throws an exception. I'm using jdk1.8.0_31.

```
[bin]$ Exception in thread "AeshProcess: 2" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4148)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4466)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1221)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:559)
at org.jboss.aesh.console.export.ExportManager.parseValue(ExportManager.java:178)
at org.jboss.aesh.console.export.ExportManager.parseValue(ExportManager.java:197)
```

Comment: Tried the same versions of JBoss Forge and JDK in a Windows 7 VM and it worked fine.

Comment: Does this still happen in Forge 2.18.0.Final?